# Problema con el modelo Productor-Consumidor

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:
"*Se definen 3 clases, la clase **Cola** que será el objeto compartido entre el productor y el consumidor, y las clases **Productor** y **Consumidor**. El productor produce números y los coloca en una cola, estos serán consumidos por el consumidor. El recurso a compartir es la cola con los números,"

El productor debe generar números de 0 a 5 en un bucle for, y los pone en el objeto **Cola** mediante el método put(); después se visualiza y se hace una pausa con sleep()*

Esta parte del ejercicio la tengo solucionada de la siguiente forma: 
**Clase Cola**

```
package psp2_multihilo_libro.productor_consumidor;

public class Cola {
    private int numero;
    private boolean disponible;

    public Cola() {
        disponible = false;
    }

    public synchronized int get() {
        while(!disponible) { 
            try {
                wait(); //Espero mientras la cola este vacia
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        disponible = false; //Al obtener el numero, la cola se queda vacia
        notify(); //Notifico al productor que la cola esta vacia
        //System.out.println("Se consume: "+numero);
        return numero; //devuelvo el numero
    }

    public synchronized void put(int valor) {
        while(disponible) {
            try {
                wait(); //Espero mientras la cola este llena
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        numero = valor; //Coloco el numero en la cola
        disponible = true; //Al colocar el numero, la cola se queda llena
        //System.out.println("Se produce: "+numero);
        notify(); //Notifico al consumidor que la cola esta llena
    }
}
```

**Clase Consumidor**

```
package psp2_multihilo_libro.productor_consumidor;

public class Consumidor extends Thread {
    private Cola cola;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int n;

    public Consumidor(Cola cola, int n) {
        this.cola = cola;
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String valor;
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            valor = cola.get();
            System.out.println(valor);

            /*try {
                sleep(600);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}*/
        }
    }
}
```

**Clase Productor**

```
package psp2_multihilo_libro.productor_consumidor;

public class Productor extends Thread {
    private Cola cola;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int n;

    public Productor(Cola cola, int n) {
        this.cola = cola;
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            cola.put(i);

            try {
                sleep(600);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        System.out.println("Fin productor...");
        end = true;
    }
}
```

Ahora, la segunda parte del ejercicio dice así:
*"Ahora, prueba a hacer lo mismo pero cono 2 consumidores. La salida debe ser parecida a esta, en el productor se producen todas las iteraciones, en los consumidores no, ya que solo se producen números de 5 iteraciones."*
Salida propuesta:

```
0 => Productor 1: produce 0
     0 => Consumidor 1: consume 0
     0 => Consumidor 2: consume 1
1 => Productor 1: produce 1
     1 => Consumidor 1: consume 2
2 => Productor 1: produce 2
     1 => Consumidor 2: consume 3
3 => Productor 1: produce 3
     2 => Consumidor 1: consume 4
4 => Productor 1: produce 4
Fin productor...
```

Y aquí, es donde no consigo llegar a ningún lado, si declaro e instancio otro consumidor, tengo el problema de que, cuando termina el productor, ambos consumidores que quedan a la espera y no tengo idea de como se puede solucionar.

Comment: notify Despierta un hilo dormido al azar, prueba con notifyAll();

Comment: Ademas me parece que los ciclos for de Productor y consumidor estan de mas, ya que el productor debe insertar un numero del 0 al 5 y el consumidor solo debe sacar dicho numero de la cola. Sino deberias hacer un array de numeros en la clase cola del cual se pondrian y sacarian los numeros producidos por el productor